# Java Comparing object Lists to find duplicates and putting them in a new list

Tags: java, list, object, compare

When comparing two lists of the same object to find where they are duplicated the list with both in come up empty.

```
List<Appointment> appointmentByName = sM.getAppointmentByName(first.getText(),last.getText());
List<Appointment>appointmentByDate=sM.getAppointmentByDate(LocalDate.now());System.out.println(appointmentByName);
//Populating the lists (This works)


List<Appointment> common = appointmentByDate.stream().filter(appointmentByName::contains).collect(toList());
```

Once the lists are populated I want to find the appointment objects that are the same and put them into a new list e.g.

```
List1 [Appointment@20, Appointment@c3, Appointment@d9, Appointment@175]
List2 [Appointment@23, Appointment@175]
List3 [Appointment@175]
```

equals override in the Appointment class

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Appointment)) return false;
    Appointment that = (Appointment) o;
    return id == that.id;
}
```

However the common list is empty, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soloution;
Changed the equals override in the Appointment class from

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
if (this == o) return true;
if (!(o instanceof Appointment)) return false;
Appointment that = (Appointment) o;
return id == that.id;
}
```

to

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
if (this == o) return true;
if (!(o instanceof Appointment)) return false;
Appointment that = (Appointment) o;
return id.equals(that.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but it seems to me that you are trying to do an intersection of two Lists here. If yes, you can do it with Collection's retainAll() method:

```
list1.retainAll(list2)
```

list1 will now contain duplicates of both lists only

Comment: This worked for compairing them, turns out my problem was with the equals method.